# What does application.match return? an integer?

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing some issues with the `application.match` function. Type mismatch.
What is the type of data that `application.match` returns? an integer?

Any way that I can change the type of `l` and `k` below to allow me to work with them using `cells(l,k)`?

```
Sub otcheck()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 384 To 395
        j = check(i)

        Range("O9") = mthdate(j)
        Range("O10") = mthdate(j - 1)

        If Range("O10") = #12:00:00 AM# Then
            l = 9    
        Else
            l = Application.Match(Range("O10"), Range("B9:B500"), 0)
        End If

        k = Application.Match(Range("O9"), Range("B9:B500"), 0)

        Cells(i, 4) = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(l, 14), Cells(k, 14)))
        'this above line is having the type mismatch issue
        'guessing is due to the l and k variables
    Next i

    Range("o9:P10") = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter 1 in a cell, select it then enter in the Immediate window:

```
? typename(application.match(1,selection,0))
```

outputs "Double"

You should use a `Variant` though, so you can test the return value for an error in the case where there's no match found:

```
Dim l As Variant
l = Application.Match(Range("O10"), Range("B9:B500"), 0)
If IsError(l) Then
    'no match!
Else
    'use l
End If
```

Don't forget that (for example) l / k values of 1 would correspond to Row9, not Row1 (because your lookup range is B9:B500)